# JPL textToTerm only produces anonymous variables

Tags: java, prolog, swi-prolog, jpl

I'm using JPL to do some SWI-Prolog queries in a Java program. When I want to create a new Query, I would like to be able to use `jpl.Util.textToTerm` to directly instanciate Terms from a user input, without parsing it myself.

The problem is that this method seems to always parse variable identifiers (i.e. something that starts with a capital letter) as anonymous variables (i.e. something that starts with `_`).

For example, `jpl.Util.textToTerm("X")` returns a `jpl.Variable` that has name `_1` instead of `X`, which is obviously a problem since that means I won't be able to access any bindings after querying.

Creating a `jpl.Query` directly from a string, like `new Query("reverse([1,2],X)")` has the exact same problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`_1` it's **not** an anonymous variable, so the problem is less important than it appears at first glance.

Variables with the same name (actually, the **same** variable) will have the same representation once returned from the JPL interface. Otherwise, you should file a bug of the mailing list...

You should use [read_term](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=read_term/2) family of predicates passing as option `variable_names(Vars)`. For instance, on the REPL

```
?- read_term_from_atom('a(X,Y,X)',T,[variable_names(L)]).
T = a(_G1434, _G1435, _G1434),
L = ['X'=_G1434, 'Y'=_G1435].
```

*edit* a quick test reusing JPL test infrastructure (I've named the file TestQuery.java)

```
import java.util.Map;

import org.jpl7.Query;
import org.jpl7.Term;

public class TestQuery {
    public static void main(String argv[]) {
        Query q = new Query("X = 1");
        Map<String, Term>[] solutions = q.allSolutions();
        System.out.println(solutions[0]);
    }
}
```

outputs

```
./run.sh
Compiling TestQuery

JPL demo: TestQuery

{X=1}
```

so, maybe I don't understand your problem in first place, sorry... Are you using an up-to-date installation ?

Comment: I don't get how this can help. Say I create a Query `query  = new Query("X = 1")`. `query.nextSolution()` will return an empty Hashtable, instead of  one containing the binding X = 2. What does `read_term_from_atom` have to do with this?

Comment: What you describe seems a different problem than what is requested in the question. The hashtable should contain the binding `_1 = 1`

Comment: Well it does not, I pointed out " I won't be able to access any bindings after querying" in my question. `_1` is not an anonymous variable `_` but it's like a `don't-want-to-know` variable. It seems logical that I get nothing in the hastable since it's that type of variable, I just dont get why it gets renamed to this,  when creating a variable `new Variable("X")` works fine.

Comment: Using `allSolutions` I still get an empty binding. So I guess it comes from my JPL jar or linked libraries. I see that your JPL classes are in package `org.jpl7`, whereas mine are just in `jpl`. I got my jar and the linked libraries from the lib and bin directories of my SWI-Prolog install, and I don't see where else I can get them, there's no download link on  the JPL webpage.

Comment: Which would also explain why when I ran queries using JPL on version 7 Strings (with quotes `"`), it acted like an old SWI-Prolog version that considers `"` to be character codes.

Comment: Such basic constructs should not have been changed, but since I build SWI-Prolog from sources, I cannot test right now. If you are on Windows, the easier way should be just to download and reinstall...

Comment: I reinstalled it and the jpl.jar seems now to be the same as yours (package org.jpl7 exists in it), but now a simple query doesn't even run and outputs a lot of errors like `Message: error(instantiation_error,context(system: $set_predicate_attribute/3,_G74))`

Comment: I installed SWI-Prolog on another computer and got JPL to work right away like in your example. I'll accept your answer since it helped me identify exactly what's wrong.